# Is there a way to put URLs in the same document using Mermaid Markdown flowchart?

Tags: url, markdown, mermaid

I'm using Mermaid Markdown to draw flowcharts for my projects, then export the generated pages as PDF to make them viewable for external people.

On this [link](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart), I have seen that it was possible to put URL like this :

```
graph LR;
    A-->B;
    click A callback "Tooltip for a callback"
    click B "http://www.github.com" "This is a tooltip for a link"
```

This is an external URL, but I would like something that would point to an anchor (a title / subheading) in the same page. Is there a way to do that ?

An example of URLs that I would like would be generated in pure Markdown as this (but I would like to use them in the Mermaid flowchart) :

```
[Text](#subheading-title)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using Mermaid flowchart inside Vuepress with vuepress-plugin-mermaidjs. Got it working inside a .md file like this:

````
# Title

## section1

text inside section 1

## section2 

text inside section

```mermaid
graph LR;
    A-->B;
    click A "./#section1"
````